# How to convert File path to Content Uri in Android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-contentresolver

I am going on with my surfceview in that i had stored the image in SDCard by seperate folder by File path from that how to get MimeType it set the type as **NULL**.

How can i get the MimeType from local file path but by default calling the intent i can get the MimeType .

For that tried to convert the File path to Content Uri but no changes if someone have idea about this please help me friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to get MimeType from Filepath:

```
  String extention =  stringUri.substring(stringUri.lastIndexOf("/"));
            String mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(extention);
            String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                    .getMimeTypeFromExtension(mimeTypeMap);
```